# remove_dot_segments seems to turn relative paths into absolute paths

Tags: url, rfc3986

["5.2.4.  Remove Dot Segments"](https://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-5.2.4) of Std 66 explains how to convert a path with `.` and `..` into one without.

IIUC, the input `foo/../bar` is processed as follows.

1. Per step 1, the (input buffer, output buffer) are initialized to (`"foo/../bar"`, `""`)
2. Step 2.E is applied to get (`"/../bar"`, `"foo"`)
3. Step 2.C is applied to get (`"/bar"`, `""`)
4. Step 2.E is applied to get (`""`, `"/bar"`)
5. The step 2 loop exits
6. Per step 3, the result is `/bar`.

It seems odd to me that the input is a relative path, but the output is an absolute path.

It seems to me this could be fixed by, in Step 1, setting *isAbsolute* to true iff the input buffer starts with a `/` and changing Step 2.C from

> C.  if the input buffer begins with a prefix of "/../" or "/..",
>              where ".." is a complete path segment, then replace that
>              prefix with "/" in the input buffer and remove the last
>              segment and its preceding "/" (if any) from the output
>              buffer; otherwise,

to

> C.  if the input buffer begins with a prefix of "/../" or "/..",
>              where ".." is a complete path segment, then replace that
>              prefix with "/" in the input buffer and remove the last
>              segment and its preceding "/" (if any) from the output
>              buffer, **then if not *isAbsolute* and the output buffer
>              is empty, remove the "/" from the front of the input buffer**;
>         otherwise,

---

Am I misreading the spec?  Is that the desired result for some reason I'm not seeing?

I put together a [gist](https://gist.github.com/mikesamuel/b57c92975fc14d8e0bbb4ebfcf2baece) with a Java implementation of my understanding of the spec and the "fix" I proposed.